# jenkins jacoco code coverage html report goes missing after sometime

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

I have jenkins setup ready, up and running and after every build it calculates code coverage and display code coverage trend graph as well detailed HTML report.

But when I click on the same link to check my detailed HTML report I see a blank page something like this[image: Jacoco Code Coverage]

I am using 1.0.16 version of jenkins jacoco plugin.

Any clue

Answer (score 1):

Finally have got the solution for this. Posting incase someone is facing same issue.
This is actually a bug which has been raised here 
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23708

In the bug you will find attachment called jacoco.hpi, upload this file onto jenkins and then restart the server. This will work.